# Controlling for a variable: t-test or covariate?

Tags: regression, t-test, predictor, controlling-for-a-variable

Lets say I have some data that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame('id' = c(1:4), 'group' = c('A','A','B','B'),
                 'score' = c(1,5,3,7), 'ability' = c(7,3,1,1))

  id group score ability
1  1     A     1       7
2  2     A     5       3
3  3     B     3       1
4  4     B     7       1
```

Each subject is assigned to a `group`. We measure their `score` on some test, which is the outcome of interest. Additionally, we measure their `ability` on some other related task

I'm primarily interested in whether mean `score` is different between groups A and B, but I may also need to control for their `ability`. In my mind there are 2 ways I could do this:

**Option 1**

The typical approach would just be a regression with `ability` included as a covariate:

```
lm(score ~ group + ability, data=df)
```

**Option 2**

If my concern is that there may be an `ability` difference between the groups, I could first run a t-test to check whether that is the case. If that t-test is non-significant, then just run a regression without the `ability` covariate:

```
t.test(ability ~ group, data=df)
lm(score ~ group, data=df)
```

**Questions**

My gut tells me that Option 1 is more appropriate but I'm not entirely sure why.

1. If there is no `ability` difference, is there any need to actually
   control for it in the model? I believe we would save a degree of
   freedom by leaving it out of the model
2. Is the covariate approach capturing something that the t-test can't capture? Covariance between `ability` and `score`? When might that be important to model?
3. What does the covariate approach actually "control" for, and how does it achieve that? My understanding is that the coefficient for `group` is for the mean level of `ability` (i.e. controlling for `ability` by holding it constant at its mean). Doesn't the non-significant t-test eliminate the need for this, as the means of the 2 groups are essentially the same?

In general, if someone advocates for the t-test approach, what would be the statistical arguments against it?

Answer (score 1):

Linear model approach:

Let $Y$ be score, $X_1$ group, and $X_2$ ability.

1. Fit model 
   $$Y=\beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2 + \beta_3X_1X_2+ \epsilon$$
   If rejecting that $\beta_3 = 0$ then stop here. The difference between groups depends on ability. You need to plug in the dirrenet values of ability to get the differences at the different ability. If accepting that $\beta_3 = 0$, goto step 2.
2. fit model $$Y=\beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2 +\epsilon$$

$$Y=\beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2 + \beta_3X_1X_2+ \epsilon$$
If rejecting that $\beta_2 = 0$ then stop here. The difference between groups does not depends on ability and is the same across the ability, which is $\beta_1$ . If accepting that $\beta_2 = 0$, goto step 3.

3. fit model $$Y=\beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 +\epsilon$$
   which is exact the same as t-test.